# How does a compiler identify its host machine's hardware? Which component?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, systems-programming, intermediate-code

My teacher told me that the intermediate code is generic for all systems but a component of the compiler then make it different according the system/environment the code is run on. Can someone please explain it.

Comment: Are you talking about the host where the compiler is running or the host where the compiled binary is running on later?

Comment: Thanks for clarification. If you were asking about the compil**ed** binary, it would go in a different direction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Normally a compiler is divided into two parts: A frontend that does the parsing, and which generates intermediate code. Then a backend which takes the intermediate code and generate the assembly or machine code.

The frontend can be generic, but the backend is built for a specific *target*. So the compiler doesn't have to "identify" the host, only know the target.

Note that host and target may be different systems, which is used for [*cross compilation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler).

Comment: Well, rather three parts, as the major part of the backend is machine-independent as well - it'd be a hell otherwise.